# Write listeners for Views getting from OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, listener, onitemclicklistener

List View and Custom Adapter in different classes. 
Custom Adapter have 2 textViews

In OnItemClickListener i created listeners for textviews. 
TextView listeners some time working some time not working.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                final int pos, final long id) {

            TextView tv1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv1);

            tv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(act, "tv1 clicked", 300).show();
                }
            });

            TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv2);

            tv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    Toast.makeText(act, "tv2 clicked", 300).show();
                }
            });

            // listViewListeners(parent, view, pos, id);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Question is why you are adding Listeners in `onItemClick` ? which will not work properly. why not adding click listeners in Custom Adapter class ?

Comment: List View and Custom Adapter in different classes and my adapter need to use multiple activities.

Comment: Set Listeners in Adapter's getView(). Follow  the Custom list adapters tutorials. 
"my adapter need to use multiple activities" What that suppose to do with list item click.

Comment: Adapter's getView() i already used its working. I need OnItemClickListener approach. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to register click event on child views when clicked on parent, so for the first time it won't work as parent will take the touch from user, but based on child element elevation and event listener, it takes clicks from child.

To avoid those use interface

```
interface ClickListener{
  void tvOneClicked(int position);
  void tvTwoClicked(int position);
}
```

and while calling your adapter from activity pass above interface as in

```
adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,some_layout,somedata, new ClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void tvOneClicked(int position){
        //Toast.makeText(act, "tv1 clicked", 300).show(); 
     }

     @Override
     public void tvOneClicked(int position){
        //Toast.makeText(act, "tv2 clicked", 300).show(); 
     }});
```

And in your `Adapter`, use this to call `activity` when any of your `textview` 
clicked

```
private ClickListener clickListener;
 public CustomAdapter(Activity act,int layout,List<> data, ClickListener listener){ 
    this.clickListener = listener;
 }

 public void getView(...){

   ...
    tv1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                     clickListener.onOneClicked(position);
                }
            });
            tv2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    clickListener.onTwoClicked(position);
                }
            });
   ...
  }
```